# Generate form based on form selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, select

I have a dropdown selection box to generate another select box based on the selection of the first box. I have put an example below.

```
<form action="" method="type">
<select name="Semester">
<option value="Fall2013">Fall 2013</option>
<option value="Spring2013">Spring 2013</option>
</select>
```

I would like to put the classes that the student is enrolled in for the selected semester in
a select box so then I can have them enter homework for the selected class. I would like to keep it as simple as possible as I am just learning MySQL/PHP. The semesters and classes will be pulled from a MySQL database based on what user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

suppose `$row` array that is fetched by your mysql query, now what you would do is...

```
<form action="" method="type">
<select name="Semester">

    <?php  foreach($row as $uniqe) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $unique ?> "> <?php echo $unique ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>

</select>
```

So, the above code Will generate all data stored in `$row` one by one

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery and AJAX to get the classes based on the selection in the first drop down. Here is a tutorial on how to accomplish it:

http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html

**Edit:**
A simpler approach (from a programmer's standpoint, not the end-user's standpoint) would be do just use PHP and do a step/page approach. i.e. user makes a selection on step/page 1 and submits the form to page 2. Step/page 2 then uses PHP to query the database and get the classes to display to the user.

Comment: Simma down! OP says: "I would like to keep it as simple as possible as I am just learning MySQL/PHP."
@OP You don't need to use AJAX, thats a much more advanced way to do it (despite my propensity to agree with Revent- I'd use AJAX too, but it is by no means necessary)

Comment: Exactly. That's why I linked to an article for beginners. Best way to learn is by going through a simple tutorial.